# Send Message in specific time via js

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot

How Can I send  1 Message just to 10 chatIds in 1 min and again send to 10 next chatIds in one min until my chatIds Finish?
I mean I will want to send a message to all chatIds with 1min latency

```
$chatIds = array("xxx","xxx","xxx",......);
```

This Code Just Send 1 Message to 1 person (msg.chat.id)

```
const StartKeyboard = [
  ['a', 'b'],
  ['send']
]

bot.onText(/\/send/, (msg) => {
  const opts = {
    reply_to_message_id: msg.message_id,
    reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
      keyboard: StartKeyboard,
      resize_keyboard: true,
      one_time_keyboard: true
    })
  };
  bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, `Hello`, opts);
});
```

I Want to use some `(foreach($chatIds as $chatId) {)` and `(setInterval)` But I Don't Know How Should I use.

Comment: code is a bit unclear. What is "/\/send/" event doing here?

Comment: You can just splice the array with chatIds.splice(0, 10) and send to those ten ids only and use interval like this :

setInterval(() => sendMessage(chatIds.splice(0,10)), 60000);

Comment: Thank You , Can You Update my code? I'm new in Dev

Comment: where does the msg data come from? Also, whats chatIds array data actually. Given from msg object you are using, msg. message_id, msg.chat.id, you must have same format in chatIds array

Comment: Forexmaple i stored my chat ids in a local json { "chatids":{},{},.........}

Comment: my Git (https://github.com/saeedhei/Ntba-Message-Receiver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If chatIds object like this :

```
chatIds = [{message_id: 123, chat: {id : 456}}, {message_id: 234, chat: {id : 567}} ];
```

what you may do is :

```
    setInterval(() => {
      chatIds.splice(0,10).forEach((msg) => {
      const opts = {
        reply_to_message_id: msg.message_id,
        reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
          keyboard: StartKeyboard,
          resize_keyboard: true,
          one_time_keyboard: true
        })
      };
       bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, `Hello`, opts);
    });}, 60000);
```

Comment: @SedricHeidarizarei Please next time on SO, add as much information as possible. Like here you could've added chatIds object format and bot details